# Getting key error in python

Tags: python, pandas

i am getting key error at `Y = df['people'].values` don't know why,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import linear_model
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("project.csv")

print(df.shape)
df.head()

X = df['day'].values
Y = df['people'].values
```

Comment: What is `print(df.columns.tolist())` ?

Comment: i didn't get your point what are you trying to say?

Comment: It means there is no column `people`

Comment: but in my csv file the column exist.

Comment: https://ufile.io/hmppl  check the file i uploaded here @jezrael

Comment: error opening file

Comment: there is sapce in column name, need `df['people ']`

Comment: ahh! i got this there is a space in column name and in my code i forgot! Thanks to @jezrael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is problem whitespace in column name.

```
df = pd.read_csv("project.csv")
print (df.head())
   day  people 
0    1        3
1    2        1
2    3        0
3    4        2
4    5        5

print (df.columns.tolist())
['day', 'people ']

print (df['people '])

#solution for remove trailing spaces
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
print (df['people'])
```